# How can i solve npm error on install -g yarn?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

i want to run this command and install yarn

`npm install -g yarn`

but i get this error

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
npm ERR! path C:\Users\DigiMax\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn bash ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DigiMax\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-03T15_03_24_683Z-debug.log
```

how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem solve by "running VSCode as administrator"

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution is `npm cache clean` and `npm cache verify` works in most cases.

According to [docs.npmjs](https://docs.npmjs.com/common-errors#many-enoent--enotempty-errors-in-output) you should check your npm version and update if needed or reinstall it at worst.

Please, let us know if it worked

Comment: I did these things, but the problem was not solved

Comment: i also have same issue with vue js app. When i want to serve my new app i get same error